# Is is possible to create a custom view when accessing ftp folders through a browser?

Tags: php, html, css, browser, ftp

I have a number of ftp accounts on my website where each account is accessible by a limited number of people. The accounts can be accessed for download by going to ftp.mysite.com in a browser. I would like to make the directory display look like the rest of the site when people goto ftp.mysite.com.  Is this possible?

Edit: Not using any special software, just typing the ftp.mysite.com into the browser address bar

Comment: Need more information, including what software you're using to display FTP in a browser.  Is it something that your host does? Is it something you can change?

Comment: question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah consider using a ftp script. I use this one:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwebftp/.

This gives you a php script that you can style just like your site. Then just point them to your script instead of the ftp site itself. The script has most of the functionality that a regular ftp site has.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into this as solution to my problem.

Comment: This was the most appropriate answer. Although I found that there is a limit on the file size downloadable when using a php script.